# Need help in time series data using R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm new to time series data and how to analyze/ process it in R. I have a data frame which contains details on currency exchange rate (USD to Euro) on a daily basis from 2012 to 2015. Here is how the dataframe, dfEurUSDExchange, looks like.

```
ExchangeDate | ExchangeRate |   Year |   YrMon   |   YrQtr  
2012-01-01   |   0.772484   |   2012 |   2012-01 |   2012-Q1   
2012-01-02   |   0.773471   |   2012 |   2012-01 |   2012-Q1   
2012-01-03   |   0.766388   |   2012 |   2012-01 |   2012-Q1   
2012-01-04   |   0.772803   |   2012 |   2012-01 |   2012-Q1   
2012-01-05   |   0.781781   |   2012 |   2012-01 |   2012-Q1
```

I understand that I can use the function ts() to convert this to a time series object. But I'm facing some issues. Here is what I'm trying.

```
tsEurUSDExchange = ts(dfEurUSDExchange, start = 2012, frequency = 365)
```

I get a warning saying "In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion". I believe this is due to the character data present under YrMon and YrQtr.

Question#1: What can I do to resolve this warning?
Question#2: How can I utilize the date column ExchangeDate?
Question#3: How can I use ts.plot to plot only ExchangeRate against the time 
            index in tsEurUSDExchange?

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: Try converting your YrMon to a date format using `as.POSIXct (dfEurUSDExchange$YrMon, format="%&-%m")` and convert `as.Factor(dfEurUSDExchange$YrQtr)`. It might solve the problem of coercion.

Comment: It's honestly easier to start as xts or zoo and convert back to ts if you need.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what is the difference between ts, xts and zoo. Can you help me?

Comment: At the moment, I dropped this column YrMon. Now I'm able to convert to ts.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `xts` library, not `ts()` from base R:

```
library(xts)
# Create dat by reading tmp_file
dat <- read.table(text = "ExchangeDate | ExchangeRate |   Year |   YrMon   |   YrQtr
2012-01-01   |   0.772484   |   2012 |   2012-01 |   2012-Q1
2012-01-02   |   0.773471   |   2012 |   2012-01 |   2012-Q1
2012-01-03   |   0.766388   |   2012 |   2012-01 |   2012-Q1
2012-01-04   |   0.772803   |   2012 |   2012-01 |   2012-Q1
2012-01-05   |   0.781781   |   2012 |   2012-01 |   2012-Q1", 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, sep ="|")

# Convert dat into xts
dat.xts <- xts(dat[,2:ncol(dat)], order.by = as.Date(dat[,1], "%Y-%m-%d"))


plot.zoo(dat.xts)
```

The date column must be read in independently, here I've used the `order.by` argument. The date column must then be omitted from the dependent variables.

Comment: What is the difference between using ts and xts? Also, do I need to even keep the date column anymore? Because now as part of time series, it has created a time index.

Comment: In a nutshell, xts is more user-friendly and backwards compatile with zoo and ts. For details, read the xts vignettes. You can convert your xts object to ts or zoo objects anytime you want to, using `as.ts()`, `as.zoo()`.   xts treats all data as a matrix rather than a data frame. The index column *must* be in an iso-compatible date format. index is in a way similar to concept of rownames() in a data frame (but nonoptional and more strict w.r.t type).

Comment: Thank you. I got the difference now.